# three.js example of TubeGeometry throws exception in r85

Tags: javascript, exception, three.js, geometry

I wanted to use `TubeGeometry` in three.js to draw a helix (spring). But I can't get even the simplest example to work. I tried using the example given in the three.js docs [here](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/geometries/TubeGeometry) but it throws an exception down in the bowels of three.js. The jsfiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/richardylewright/r6ge1xvr/3/). Here is the exception stack:

```
VM103 three.js:25150 Uncaught TypeError: path.computeFrenetFrames is not a function
    at new TubeBufferGeometry (VM103 three.js:25150)
    at new TubeGeometry (VM103 three.js:25111)
    at createSinCurve (VM102:102)
    at window.onload (VM102:49)
```

On the example page is a graphic that looks like it might come from the code on the example page, but if you look at the source you find that it doesn't use the THREE.TubeGeometry at all, but another library entirely—`THREE.ParametricGeometries`.

Am I missing something? Or is `THREE.TubeGeometry` now deprecated and the docs are wrong?

Comment: It looks like it is an error in the documentation and TubeGeometry doesn't support a parametric callback form anymore. Alternatively, it is a bug.  In any case, I found a different way to do it by building an array of Vector3 objects, passing that to a CatmullRomCurve3 object and using that curve as the path.  Worked like a charm.  You can see the result [here](http://www.geofx.com/graphics/nehe-three-js/lessons33-40/lesson39/lesson39webgl.html) and the source code is [here](https://github.com/rkwright/nehe-three-js/tree/develop/lesson39).

Comment: See fix to your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/r6ge1xvr/4/

Comment: I fixed it just by moving the `init(); createSizeCurve(); animate();` stack to the bottom of the code where they belong. :)

Comment: It's a bit off topic, but in your lesson you used scaling for the spring and it looks strange, when the diameter of the wire changes during compression. So, the [first approach](https://jsfiddle.net/prisoner849/2xcsp0nb/) with `.morphTargets` gave an inappropriate visual result, and so far I've ended up with [dynamic geometry](https://jsfiddle.net/prisoner849/tjmpkkog/).

Comment: @WestLangley (and TheJim01)  Thanks for pointing out my error.  Much appreciated!

Comment: @prisoner849 Very interesting.  I had seen a mention of morphTargets, but haven't studied them.  Now I will.  thanks